# Vapor migrate command not found

Tags: swift, migration, migrate, vapor

I installed a swift vapor web-server and I have to run some migrations. Reading from the docs(https://docs.vapor.codes/fluent/migration/?h=migrate#migrate) it says that I just have to run vapor run migrate but all I get is an error that says `.unknownCommand("migrate", available: ["boot", "serve", "routes"])`. It seems the vapor toolbox doesn't have the `migrate` command. I installed the vapor toolbox following the docs(https://docs.vapor.codes/install/linux/#install-toolbox):

```
git clone https://github.com/vapor/toolbox.git
cd toolbox
git checkout <desired version>
make install
```

To be fair i had some problems with the `make install` comand. It said that swiftc wasn't a valid comand but I just changed swiftc to swift inside the Makefile and it did compile at the end. As a matter of fact the `vapor --version` command works.
I use swift 5.5 and vapor 4. Does anybody now how to fix this or find some workaround like running the migration file by itself without the command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really use the vapor toolbox anymore. I put the second line in `main.swift` in the `Sources/App/Run` folder:

```swift
// earlier lines omitted
try configure(app)
try app.autoMigrate().wait() // <-- this one needs to be in this position
try app.run()
```

It needs to be after everything has been configured but before you start the app running.

Comment: I added the line of code but nothing happens. I'm kind of new with this vapor stuff so it could be some dumb mistake. Anyway, whenever I run `.build/debug/Run serve` the server seems to start but when I take a look to the DB (MySQL) no tables have been added. Credentials for the DB are inside a .env. Migrations are inside Sources/App/Migrations/. I tried to print something after `try app.autoMigrate().wait()` just to make sure it gets executed but everything seems fine. I was also trying to find some type of log that vapor generates but I can't find any. The only logs I found are from nginx.

Comment: Are you adding the migrations in configure.swift? E.g.app.migrations.add(CreateUnitTable())

Comment: No there's not. But there's a file called migrations.swift with a bunch of `Migration.create*(on: database)`, and the class extends AsyncMigration. I guess I can call this class to do the migrations? I'm sorry but I didn't write this project and the guy who did doesn't really now how to deploy this on a server